# Cannot create application in eXide

Tags: exist-db

I just wanted to create a new application to try out some smaller things, when I realised I cannot create a new application from eXide:

[image: 1]

I am running eXist-db 6.2.0 under openSuse Tumbleweed.
Has anyone else experienced this before?

Answer (score 1):

The current version of eXide is 3.5.0. As noted in the [eXide repository's README](https://github.com/eXist-db/eXide#note-concerning-exide-300):

> eXide 3.0.0 removes the app generation feature as it was generating outdated code with potential security risks. We recommend the much better yeoman-based [generator-exist](https://github.com/eXist-db/generator-exist) for eXist-db.

An archive of past releases of eXide is available via https://github.com/eXist-db/eXide/releases.

Comment: somehow that slipped my eye! Haven't started a new app in ages :-D